# fork() and output

Tags: c++, linux, unix, fork

I have a simple program:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << " Hello World";
    fork();
}
```

After the program executes my output is: `Hello World Hello World`. Why does this happen instead of a single `Hello world`? I'm guessing that the child process is rerun behind the scenes and the output buffer is shared between the processes or something along those lines, but is that the case or is something else happening?

Comment: This is what fork does it spawns the process with the memory of the parent. http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork

Comment: There sure have been a lot of `fork()` questions lately... hmm...

Comment: hm.. Child process start execute code of program after calling of fork.  So the child process just cannot cannot execute code which are above fork.

Comment: I don't think interviews. I think a OS class. See latest refactormycode.com: http://refactormycode.com/codes/2011-linux-shell

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This isn't quite what you thought originally.  The output buffer is not shared - when you execute the fork, **both processes get a copy of the same buffer**.  So, after you fork, both processes eventually flush the buffer and print the contents to screen separately.

This **only happens because cout is buffered IO**.  If you used cerr, which is not buffered, you should only see the message one time, pre-fork.

Comment: This only happens because cout is userspace-buffered IO. ^_^

Answer (score 44):

standard output uses buffered IO. When the `fork()` is called the standard output is not flushed and the buffered content is replicated in the child process. These buffers are flushed when the process exit, resulting in the two outputs that you see.

If you change the program to:

```
std::cout << " Hello World;" << std::endl;
```

you should see only one.

Answer (score 17):

Because you called fork() without flushing all buffers first.

```
cout.flush();
fork();
```

Answer (score 10):

The code to output `"Hello World"` is only executed once. The issue is that the output buffer isn't flushed. So when you fork the process, `"Hello World"` is still sitting in the output buffer. When both programs exit, their output buffers will be flushed and you'll see the output twice.

The easiest way to demonstrate this is by adding a newline at the end of your string, which will cause an implicit flush, or explicitly flush with `std::cout.flush();`. Then you'll only see the output once.

Answer (score 9):

If you use:

```
std::cout << " Hello World" << std::flush;
```

You only see one. I guess `fork()` copies whatever output buffer `std::cout` writes to.

Answer (score 6):

The string is not immediately written to the screen; instead, it's written to an internal buffer. The child process inherits a copy of the output buffer, so when the child's `cout` is automatically flushed, `Hello World` is printed to the screen. The parent also prints `Hello World`.

If you flush `cout` before the `fork()`, the problem will almost certainly go away.

Comment: I wouldn't say the analysis is exactly right. The child process is not "rerun behind the scenes."

Comment: @MichaelMior: You're right. I missed the "re-run" bit. I've edited the language.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the when you invoke `std::cout<<` it doesn't really perform the output itself but data is left in a buffer in the system. When you do the fork, both code and data are copied, as well as all the buffers associated. Finally, both father and son flush them to the standard output and thus you see the output duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

What you're likely seeing here is an effect of buffering.  In general output is buffered until  it's explicitly flushed or implicitly done with an action like outputting a new line.  Because the output is buffered both copies of the forked process have bufferred output and hence both display it upon the process terminating and flushing the buffer