# understanding fork in c

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
int num = 0;
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
   printf("common line\n");  
   printf("%d", num); 
   int pid;
   pid = fork();
   if(pid == 0){       /*child*/
      num = 1;
   } else if(pid > 0){  /*parent*/
      num = 2;
   }
   printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

I above program, **common line** string is shown single time in output. **But "0" is comming twice in the results.**

**Coming outputs:**

```
common line
01
02
```

OR

```
common line
02
01
```

As per my understanding, **0** should come only once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [About fork and printf/write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647468/about-fork-and-printf-write)

Comment: You are printing it twice.

Comment: no @MartinJames, first print is forcefully for "0"

Comment: You didn't flush it.

Comment: @MartinJames that solved my problem... but what it suggests? i am little confused with this behaviour. When i am not flushing, then also 0 should come once in the buffer

Comment: @MartinJames even if i add new line to first printf, that also colves my problem

Comment: When you fork, all data is duplicated in the child process. If you fork without flushing stdout, buffered data (the 0 here) is duplicated in the child process: a '0' is printed by both process when stdout is flushed AFTER forking.

Comment: `stdout` is line buffered. you forked the line buffer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By adding a newline character at the end of your string you are implicitly flushing the output buffer before you fork. Your other option is to explicitly flush it with `fflush(stdout)`. Otherwise when you `fork()`, both processes are just spitting out whatever was still left in the buffer beforehand (in your case the unflushed buffer still contains `num` from `printf("%d", num)`).