# Counting processes after fork in for loop

Tags: c, linux, fork

I have the following code:

```
for(i=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    fork();
    printf("x ");   
}
```

I calculated that x should be printed out 6 times: twice in the first iteration and 4 times in the second.

Instead, X is printed 8 times. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fork() and output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364410/fork-and-output)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of buffering. Usually, `stdout` is line-buffered, so

```
printf("x ");
```

doesn't immediately write the `"x "` to the terminal but to the output buffer. That is copied when the process `fork()`s, so each of the four processes after the second iteration has two `"x "` in the output buffer [one from the parent/before forking in the first iteration, one from the second iteration] when it exits and eight `x`s are printed altogether.

Flush the buffer immediately after the `printf("x ");` and only six will be printed.

Comment: `fflush(stdout);` is the easiest way to follow Daniel's advice here.