# Linux output changes when redirected to a file

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

When I compile and run below code in the terminal, I get the desired result
(Only single `Parent -- pid = %d\n` line, total 15 Children created)

But when I redirect it to a separate file,  (e.g. `./result > result.txt`)
I get multiple `Parent -- pid = %d\n` lines, where I expected it to appear only once.
Also, much more children seems to have been created

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int level = 0; // depth of the process tree
    pid_t pid;
    printf("Parent -- pid = %d\n", getpid()); // expected to run only once - in the top parent process
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            level++;
            printf("Child - %d - Level %d\n", getpid(), level);
        }
        else
            wait(NULL);
    }
    printf("End - %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Pipeline gives same weird result as redirection:

```
./result | grep "Parent" | wc -l  
./result | grep "Child" | wc -l
```

gives 16, 32

Am I missing something with redirection/pipeline?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364410/fork-and-output

Comment: Flushing the buffer solved the issue. Thank you!